# Validate decimal fractional value

Tags: c#

I need to validate some input numbers given as decimal. The input is for recording time in hours and fraction of hours like 1.25 or 2.50 or 3.00

I need to enforce entry of decimal fractional values of .00 .25 .50 .75

I could convert the decimal value to a string and then see how many decimal places it has and the values -or- would it be better to write a Regex or something similar?

Ryan

Comment: of only `.00 .25 .50 .75` ?

Comment: Have you considered restricting the choices in the UI?  Yeah, you still want back end validate like @somokroces describes, but it will cover nearly all your cases.

Comment: @flydog57, i might like that idea. I could just five them a range of hour values from 0.00 to 24.00 in a dropdown box....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the number, multiply it by 100 and check if the number modulo 25 gives you 0. (Since the numbers that are divided by 25 with no remain are X25, X50, X75, X00)

```
var number = 1.25;
if((number*100)%25==0) // valid
else // not valid
```

**Edit:**
or straight forward:

```
var number = 1.25;
if(number%0.25==0) // valid
else // not valid
```

(thanks for pointing it out in the comments section)

Comment: Use a `decimal`, not a `doubl`e if you are going to be doing floating point math  (i.e., add an `m` suffix to your literal numbers). Floating point match with doubles is an approximation.

Answer (score 3):

You could check for `value % 0.25 == 0`.

Comment: Same comment, use `0.25m` not `0.25`. Doubles are approximations and really shouldn't be used with equality checks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex `^\d*\.(00|25|50|75)$`.